# run rake task after csv parse finishes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rake task that looks a bit like this

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'csv'
namespace :tm do
  task reload: :environment do
    gzipped = open('csv link')
    csv_text = Zlib::GzipReader.new(gzipped).read
    csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, headers: true)

    csv.each do |row|
      if row[4] == 'logo url'
      else
        tmdate = Date.parse(row[10]).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        viatmdate = Date.parse(row[10]).strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
        swtmdate = row[10]
        tmlocation = row[6].split('at ')[1]
        place = row[11].split('|')[1]
        place1 = row[11].split('|')[2]
        place2 = row[11].split('|')[3]
        location = '' + place + ', ' + place1 + ', ' + place2 + ''
        tmtime = row[9]
        text = row[7].gsub('text', '')
        if text.include? '&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD'
          eventname = text.gsub('&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD', 'e')
        else
          eventname = text.gsub(/[ªÀÈÌÒÙàèìòùÁÉÍÓÚáéíóúÂÊÎÔÛâêîôûÃÑÕãñõÄËÏÖÜŸäëïöüÿ]/, '')
        end

        if text.include? '&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD'
          tmname = text.gsub('&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD', 'e')
        else
          tmname = text.gsub(/[ªÀÈÌÒÙàèìòùÁÉÍÓÚáéíóúÂÊÎÔÛâêîôûÃÑÕãñõÄËÏÖÜŸäëïöüÿ]/, '')
        end

        if text.include? ' -'
          tmnamesplit = text.split(' -')[0]
        end

        if tmname[/[^0-9]/].present?
          tmnamenn = tmname.gsub(/[^0-9]/i, '')
        end

        text2urldb = text2.where('eventtitle ILIKE ? AND eventdoortime = ? ', "%#{tmname.gsub(/[\-\:\ ]/, '%')}%", tmdate.to_s).first
        text3urldb = text3.where('product_name ILIKE ? AND delivery_time = ? AND valid_from = ?', "%#{tmname}%", tmtime.to_s, tmdate.to_s).first

        text1urldb = text1.where('product_name ILIKE ? AND specifications = ? AND promotional_text = ?', "%#{tmname}%", viatmdate.to_s, "%#{place}%").first

        if tmnamesplit.present?
          if text1urldb.blank?
            text1urldb = text1.where('product_name ILIKE ? AND specifications = ?', "%#{tmnamesplit}%", viatmdate.to_s).first
          end
          if text3urldb.blank?
            text3urldb = text3.where('product_name ILIKE ? AND delivery_time = ? AND valid_from = ?', "%#{tmnamesplit}%", tmtime.to_s, tmdate.to_s).first
          end
        end

        if text1urldb.blank?
          text1urldb = text1.where('product_name ILIKE ? AND specifications = ? AND promotional_text = ?', "%#{tmname}%", viatmdate.to_s, "%#{location}%").first
          if text1urldb.blank?
            text1urldb = text1.where('product_name ILIKE ? AND specifications = ?', "%#{tmname}%", viatmdate.to_s).first
          end
          if text1urldb.blank?
            text1urldb = text1.where('product_name ILIKE ? AND specifications = ? AND promotional_text = ?', "%#{tmname}%", viatmdate.to_s, "%#{tmlocation}%").first
          end
        end

        if text1urldb.present?
          vurl = text1urldb.merchant_deep_link
          txt = vurl
          re1 = '.*?' # Non-greedy match on filler
          re2 = '(?:[a-z][a-z]+)' # Uninteresting: word
          re3 = '.*?' # Non-greedy match on filler
          re4 = '(?:[a-z][a-z]+)' # Uninteresting: word
          re5 = '.*?' # Non-greedy match on filler
          re6 = '(?:[a-z][a-z]+)' # Uninteresting: word
          re7 = '.*?' # Non-greedy match on filler
          re8 = '(?:[a-z][a-z]+)' # Uninteresting: word
          re9 = '.*?' # Non-greedy match on filler
          re10 = '(?:[a-z][a-z]+)'    # Uninteresting: word
          re11 = '.*?'    # Non-greedy match on filler
          re12 = '((?:[a-z][a-z]+))'  # Word 1
          re = (re1 + re2 + re3 + re4 + re5 + re6 + re7 + re8 + re9 + re10 + re11 + re12)
          m = Regexp.new(re, Regexp::IGNORECASE)
          if m.match(txt)
            word1 = m.match(txt)[1]
          end
        end


        gmiurl = text3urldb.merchant_deep_link if text3urldb.present?

        gigurl = text2urldb.eventurl if text2urldb.present?

        api = HTTParty.get(URI.encode('text url' + tmname + '&when_from=' + swtmdate)).parsed_response
        api1 = api['Paging']
        api2 = api1['TotalResultCount']

        if api1.blank?
          newapi = HTTParty.get(URI.encode('texturl' + tmnamenn + '&when_from=' + swtmdate)).parsed_response
          paging = newapi['Paging']
          api2 = paging['TotalResultCount']
          if newapi.blank?
            apisplit = HTTParty.get(URI.encode('texturl' + tmnamesplit + '&when_from=' + swtmdate)).parsed_response
            pagingsplit = apisplit['Paging']
            api2 = pagingsplit['TotalResultCount']
          end
        end
        text1 = vurl
        text3 = gmiurl
        text2 = gigurl

        if api2 == 0
        else
          swurl = api['Events'].first['SwURL']
        end
        event = Event.find_by(time: row[9], date: row[10], eventname: eventname, eventvenuename: location)

        if event.present?
          event.update(event_type: word1, text: row[8], eventimage: row[4], textlink: swurl, text1link: text1, text3url: text3, text2url: text2)
        else
          Event.create(time: row[9], date: row[10], event_type: word1, text: row[8], eventimage: row[4], eventname: eventname, eventvenuename: location, textlink: swurl, text1link: text1, text3url: text3, text2url: text2)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now this is taking way to long to run (around 2-3 hours) so i was wondering if splitting it up would speed it up a bit?

If i was to take out text 1 2 and 3 out of here, So its just putting it into the db first. Then run another rake task after its populated fully? hopefully this should speed it up? So if i had this rake task called tm:reload and another task afterwards in a different file called BA:reload how would i do this?

I've gone through and indexes a few columns but thats not improved it very much.

Comment: Sounds like a plan to separate it into parts. Doing database calls for each line is not fast - better to try to do batch updates and selects.

Comment: batch updates and selects? Would you mind showing me the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do following:

- Have a Rake task to read the CSV file and create background job for each row
- Use Sidekiq as backend, this sounds like something you can easely parallelize
- Have this job execute parsing and lookup via HTTP and inserting/updating into DB
- Move all those REGEXP and Patterns into constants so they are not instantiated for every line
- clean up the code into smaller chunks/methods, perhaps by creating an object that represents the CSV row and provides accessors for all those values

Assuming: no duplicate records in the file and file can be processed in any order

I don't think that the DB is the bottleneck. It is more likely the HTTP Request you make. Before you fiddle with adding indexes or so i'd do some benchmarks to see where time is spent.

UPDATE:
Something like this (i did not run the code)

#### Rake Task:

```
...
csv.each do |row|
  ImportEventJob.perform_later row
end
```

#### Job Backend

ActiveJob is the Rails (background) Job API. You can configure a backend, I like Sidekiq, but others will work as well. Details see:

- http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html
- https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Active-Job
- http://redis.io/ (needed for sidekiq)

#### Job implementation

```
class ImportEventJob < ActiveJob::Base

  def perform(row)
    event_csv = EventCsv.new(row)

    event = Event.find_by(time: event_csv.time, date: event_csv.date, ...)
    if event
      ...
    else
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

#### EventCsv (Wrapper for a row of CSV Data)

```
class EventCsv
  RE_WITH_DIACRITICS = /[ªÀÈÌÒÙàèìòùÁÉÍÓÚáéíóúÂÊÎÔÛâêîôûÃÑÕãñõÄËÏÖÜŸäëïöüÿ]/
  def initialize(row)
    @row = row
   end

  def time
    @row[9]
  end
  ...

  def name
    text = @row[7].gsub('text', '')
    if text.include? '&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD'
      text.gsub('&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD', 'e')
    else
      text.gsub(RE_WITH_DIACRITICS, '')
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi there, Not sure how to do much of that, As i'm still kinda new to this! How would i be best doing this?

Comment: i've added some hints to get you started.